# Tried both ng-repeat and ng-options for select dropdown; query results keep coming back empty

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, undefined

First, let me make a couple of disclaimers:

1. This is my very first time posting a question here. I only do so because I've tried numerous possible solutions to similar questions over the past 24 hours and gotten nowhere.
2. I'm also a complete newbie to AngularJS (using 1.5.6). I'm starting to understand basic things like `ng-repeat`, but this one's got me stumped.

With that said, I'll try to provide as much info as I can, based on suggestions I've read out here. Hopefully someone will be able to quickly point out where I've gone wrong.

---

**OVERVIEW:**

I'm building a PHP/MySQL CRUD system with a fairly complex user form. The CRUD operations themselves are working fine, and they interact with a DB table I'll call *tableA*.

Now within the Create and Update forms, I have a `SELECT` drop-down list whose `OPTION`s will be generated via a query from a second DB table I'll call *tableB*. (*These tables both live within the same DB instance, called **mapping**.*) So, this second table contains 61,405 records, of which I'll only need 41 to act as my `OPTION`s. I've already successfully tested the SQL statement to return these 41 rows.

So after reading, watching and trying out several different approaches, I seem to be having trouble getting the SQL results carried over.

***index.php***

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="LangController">
    <label for="primaryLang" class="mr-2">Language primarily spoken:</label>
    <select id="primaryLang" ng-model="selectedLanguage" ng-options="lang.langName for lang in langs" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**NOTES:**

1. The `LangController` is defined within a page-wide `TaskController` because I thought maybe my `$scope` variables were getting conflated.
2. In place of `ng-options="lang.langName for lang in langs"`, I also tried explicitly defining `<option ng-repeat="lang in langs" value="{{ lang.langID }}">{{ lang.langName }}</option>`, to no avail.

---

***app.js***

```
app.controller('LangController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.listLangs = function() {
        $scope.langs = [];
        $_PATH = '/mapping/assets/script/';

        $http.get($_PATH + 'langs.php')
            .then(function success(e) {
                $scope.langs = e.data;
                console.log($scope.langs);
            },
            function error(e) {
                $scope.errors = e.data.errors;
            });
    };

    $scope.listLangs();
});
```

***langs.php***

```
<?php

    require '../__/db.php';

    $output = array();
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tableB WHERE countryID = 'TR' AND nameType = 'L' ORDER BY langName";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

**NOTES:**

1. I've confirmed that the DB connection parameters from *../__/db.php* are being successfully captured.
2. I confirmed in MySQL Workbench that the SQL query does return the 41 rows I wanted from *TableB*.
3. In place of the `$scope.listLangs();` statement in *app.js*, I also tried setting `ng-init="listLangs()"` on the `LangController` opening `DIV` in *index.php*, to no avail.

---

**RESULTS**

- According to Chrome web console, `console.log($scope.langs);` consistently returns an empty string (`""`). In other words, it doesn't look like `$scope.langs = [];` ever gets populated by `echo json_encode($output);`, despite verifying the DB connection strings and MySQL query results.
- This in turn results in a `SELECT` drop-down with only the *Select one* `OPTION`.
- Much of what I've written for this operation was copied directly from a similar `ng-repeat` under the `TaskController` I created for the CRUD operations because that one works perfectly OK. So I'm baffled by what I might have done wrong here. At first, I wrote this as another `TaskController` operation, but that produced a bunch of unintelligible JS console errors. Plus, since this isn't strictly a CRUD operation, I assumed it should probably go under a separate controller anyway to alleviate `$scope` confusion.

I'm not (yet) familiar with Plunker, so I don't have one to provide at this point. I'm hoping this will suffice as a call for help. I'm also hoping this is all due to something trivial and/or just plain stupid on my part. Again, I am a newbie to Angular (which I really like, by the way!).

Thanks so much in advance, and Happy New Year to all!

~ Eddie

Comment: Could you please see what $http.get returns? $http.get($_PATH + 'langs.php')
            .then(function success(e) { console.log(e) }. Does it even get there? Or does it go to the error case?

Comment: {data: "", status: 200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK"}config: headers: {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"}method: "GET"paramSerializer: ƒ (a)transformRequest: [ƒ]transformResponse: [ƒ]url: "/mapping/assets/script/langs.php"__proto__: Objectdata: ""headers: ƒ (d)arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: ""prototype: {constructor: ƒ}__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: angular.min.js:92[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object

Sorry that copying stripped out formatting. 'data' returns "" (empty string). And I did catch your (e) change.

Comment: Seems like your data object is empty, your your $http.get doesn't return any results. Can you try something like PostMan to see whether your request is correct?

Comment: Thanks, Nat, for your help. I installed Postman Interceptor on Chrome and refreshed my mapping app page. I see a dozen GET requests, all green. One of them is to 'langs.php'. I don't see anything indicating a problem. One other thought that occurred to me....a couple of weeks ago, I had a similar issue with TableA, which I built manually via MySQL Workbench. Copying the DB table from the CRUD tutorial into a new 'TableA' mysteriously solved the issue. So I'm wondering if the same is happening with 'TableB.' If so, then I'll have to look at what I'm doing wrong when building new DB tables.

Comment: Yes, the call might give you status 200 but it is not returning any data. Yes, it looks like it is a rest endpoint problem or DB problem. Because I do not see anything wrong with angurjs code

Comment: OK, I'll look into duplicating TableA, since it's working, into a new TableB. Then I can clear out its rows (only 5 right now), redo the column names and types, and figure out the most painless way to copy 61,405 records from the broken TableB to the new TableB. Hopefully that will resolve this.

Comment: Wishing you good luck!

Comment: Well, replicating the working TableA into a new TableB didn't help, but I did come up with a workaround. Since TableB is a fairly static table whose contents probably won't change much (maybe once a year, if that) and I only need a tiny subset that's even less likely to change, I decided to just export the query into a JSON file, then $http.get the JSON file. Now it works. However, I still have one more DB table to integrate. I'll probably try creating that in PhpMyAdmin rather than MySql Workbench and see if the table creation problem goes away. Thanks again!  :)